# Probar si una cosa esta ['']

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dataframe

Tengo una dataframe con una columna `Questions` y una otra `QTypes`. Me gustaria que cada linea que encontramos `['']` (es decir `[ Apóstrofo Apóstrofo]`) en `Questions` puestamos `Sections` en QTypes.

```
    QID Questions   Answers QType
0   H1  When do you think your next vacation can start? ['In next 3 months', 'In next 6 months', 'In next 1 year', 'Only once COVID-19 is under control', 'Only once COVID-19 vaccine is developed']    Multiple Choice
1   H2  What are your preferences regarding medical treatment policy (with additional cost)?    ["Doctor's availability in hotel", 'Ventilator availability in hotel', 'Tie-ups with nearby hospitals', 'Availability of medical rooms with primary first aid care']    Multiple Choice
2   H3  What is your preferences of complementary breakfast?    ['Buffet breakfast with social distancing', 'Buffet breakfast replaced with Ala-carte with limited options', 'Breakfast to be delivered in room with limited options (chargeable)', 'Packaged breakfast only']  Multiple Choice
3   H4  What is your preference for a in-hotel grocery shops for the basic necessity items and packaged food?   ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'] Likert Scale
4   H5  Consumer Personality    ['']    Multiple Choice
5   H6  What is your preference of hotel check-in?  ['Collect keys at the counter maintaining social distancing', 'Collect keys at the KIOSK using booking bar-code', 'Online Keys using the mobile App']   Multiple Choice
6   H7  What is your preference of payment during Check-out?    ['Pay at the counter maintaining social distancing', 'Pay at KIOSK', 'Online payment using the mobile App'] Multiple Choice
7   H8  What is your preference of hotel cancellation / travel date change policy?  ['Travel date change is preferred at no cost', 'Cancellation at some minimal cost (based on hotel policy)', 'Cancellation with some amount refund and hotel coupons for next visit']    Multiple Choice
8   H9  What is your preference of the guest policy?    ['Guests are allowed in living room with precautions', 'Guest are allowed only in certain designated areas', 'No guests are allowed inside hotel']  Multiple Choice
9   H10 What is your preference of the concierge service?   ['Regular concierge services', 'Online concierge service']  Multiple Choice
10  H11 Consumer Intentions ['']    Multiple Choice
```

Intenté:

```
def get_sections(l):
  print("l: ", l, "== ['']", l == [''])
  if l == ['']:
    return "Section"
  else:
    pass

df = df.head()
df.QType = df.apply(lambda row: get_sections(row['Answers']), axis = 1)
```

Pero me devuelve None:

```
1    None
2    None
3    None
4    None
5    None
Name: QType, dtype: object
```

## Actualizacion

Tambien intenté:

```
import numpy as np

s=df.Answers.apply(lambda x : ['']==x)
df['QType']=np.where(s, 'Section', '')
```

Pero obtengo `None` en cada celdas.

Y [la respuesta de Lucas Damian](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/369838/2633):

```
def get_sections(item):
    try:
        for i in item:
            if i == '':
                print(i)
                return "Section"
            else:
                pass
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

df.apply(lambda row: get_sections(row['Answers']), axis = 1)
```

Pero no cambia nada.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar modificar tu función de está manera?

Se me ocurre que puedes iterar por cada "lista" y preguntar si el valor es `''`.

```
def get_sections(item):
    try:
        for i in item:
            if i == '':
                print(i)
                return "Section"
            else:
                pass
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

df.apply(lambda row: get_sections(row['Answers']), axis = 1)
```

la salida correspondiente debería agregar `'Section'` en la fila 4 y 10